# load a jquery overlay after ajax completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, overlay

I have a web page which makes a ajax call and gets jquery code plus a new overlay div on which the jquery code is used. The jquery code got from the ajax should make the new overlay div to display but it does not display the div. How can i get the jquery code to work and display the overlay div??

Comment: Is there any code involved..?

Comment: <script>$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
var WindowHeight = $(window).height();
var WindowWidth = $(window).width();
$('#dark').css({'width':WindowWidth,'height':WindowHeight}); $('#dark').fadeTo(2000,0.75);
$('#message').css('top',  WindowHeight/2-$('#message').height()/2);
$('#message').css('left', WindowWidth/2-$('#message').width()/2);
$('#message').fadeIn(2000);
});
$('.close').click(function() {
$('#dark').fadeOut();
$('#message').fadeOut();
});
$('#dark').click(function () {
$('#dark').fadeOut();
$('#message').fadeOut();
});
});
</script>This is the basic jquery code passed

Comment: along with <div id="message">Display a thank u message and a smiley</div><div id="dark"></div> and also a style tag which contains the css. all this is passed back from a ajax call .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this can solve your problem i suppose

[Jquery Blocker Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)